# How to access the output of an array in a if-statement ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm completely new to this, I would like to do make all buttons with values where `slot.booked === 1` red and disabled.

How do I access the value of the if statement outputs?

```
const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 1;
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
          if (freeSlotsList.some(slot => slot.booked === 1)) {
            const activeButton = (<h1>Test</h1>);
            return (
              <button id={id++} className={activeButton}>
                {n} {activeButton} {id}
              </button> )
          } else {return <button id={id++}> {n} {id} </button>}
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable and use it in if condition

```
 const renderTableData = () => {
  let id = 1;

  return (
    <tr>
      {days.map((val) => (
        <td>
          {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
            const items = freeSlotsList.some(slot => slot.booked === 1) 
            if (items) {
              const activeButton = (<h1>Test</h1>)


            return (
              <button id={id++} className={activeButton}>
                {n} {activeButton} {id}
              </button>
            ) 
          } else 
              return (
                  <button id={id++}>
                    {n}  {id}
                  </button>
              )

          })}
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
}
```